# Android: download file programatically using the browser

Tags: android, download

My app has a string containing the URL to a file, typically something like a Word document or a PDF file. I want to give the user a way to download the file the same way they would if they had clicked on a link in the browser (letting the browser store it in the default location, etc).

At the moment I am doing this by launching an ACTION_VIEW intent. It works in most cases, but there are several problems with it. Often the browser window tries to display a message which for some reason immediately disappears and can't be read. Sometimes the download fails and I can't detect that. If it does succeed, all the user really sees is a small icon in the top status bar that they have to know to look for.

Is there a better way to do this? Some way to start a dedicated DOWNLOAD action instead of invoking the whole browser?

Could I download the file myself in my own code and then somehow cause it to end up in the same place as if the browser had downloaded it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it with your own code, and place it in the [\Download folder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) on the SD card. Alternatively, you could use the [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) available on API 9 and above.

Comment: Thanks. Is the Download folder guaranteed to exist on all devices? How do I obtain or express the path to that?

Comment: That's covered on the SDK Documentation linked to above (first link)

Comment: The download folder won't exist on every device, but you can create it. It's a common convention to place misc downloaded files there.