# disable browser while android using download option

Tags: android, download, android-intent

I am actually looking for a solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782169/android-download-file-programatically-using-the-browser)

I specifically need to use API 8 which does not come with the download Manager. The code that I am using is this :

```
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        browserIntent.setType(MIME_TYPE_PDF);
                        browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But the browser is coming up everytime i download a file, I want to disable the browser activity.
Any ideas please

Bhavya

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the browser or the (non-existent in your case) download manager, why not write your own download code.  It has the side effect of using a lot less system overhead, since you are not launching a separate app to do the download.

Here's an example that should be close to what you want.  `f` is a File object initialized to a path on the SD card.  `buffer_size` and `bytes` are class fields.

```
private static final int buffer_size=1024;
private static final byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];

InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream os = null;

try {
    is = new URL(url).openStream();
    os = new FileOutputStream(f);

    for (;;) {
        int count = is.read( bytes, 0, buffer_size );
        if ( count == -1 ) break;
        os.write( bytes, 0, count );
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e( TAG, "error : " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e );
}
finally {
    try { is.close(); } catch ( Exception ignore ) { ; }
    try { os.close(); } catch ( Exception ignore ) { ; }
}
```

Comment: thank for this information I have tried this but I see that with this kind of a dwnload the notification is not displayed. I was curious if there were other ways to do this

Comment: You could always post your own notification.